# ListView not getting populated with bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to build an app to scan bluetooth services that aren't paired with my device around me. However, when I click the scan button, the ListView is not populated with the devices name and android MAC address. I do not get any error when I run my code.

This is what i get in my logcat file:

**/? E/e.bluetoothtes: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000**

/com.example.bluetoothtest I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.

/com.example.bluetoothtest I/e.bluetoothtes: [GL_OOM] ClampGrowthLimit 268435456

/com.example.bluetoothtest V/Font: Change font:2

/com.example.bluetoothtest V/Font: Default family:android.graphics.Typeface@4cabfbd5

**/com.example.bluetoothtest E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.bluetoothtest**

**/com.example.bluetoothtest E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array**

**/com.example.bluetoothtest E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.bluetoothtest**

**/com.example.bluetoothtest E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array**

/com.example.bluetoothtest V/FlingOptimizerScroller: FlingOptimizerOverScroller Init

The one's in bold show up as red.

Here is my MainActivity.java file:

'''

```
package com.example.bluetoothtest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
Button ScanButton;
ListView scanListView;
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
BluetoothAdapter myAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanDevices);
    scanListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.devicesList);

    ScanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            myAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }

    });

    int permissionCheck = 
this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
    permissionCheck += 
this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");

    if (permissionCheck != 0)
    {
        this.requestPermissions(new String[]. 
{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001);
    }

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArrayList);
    scanListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
        {
            BluetoothDevice device = 
intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            stringArrayList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
}
```

'''

This is my activity_main.xml. I am, using Linear Layout:

'''

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/scanDevices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Scan"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>




<ListView
    android:id="@+id/devicesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scanDevices"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.579" >
</ListView>
```

'''

I have added the following permissions to my AndroidManifest file:

'''

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

'''

Comment: Can you confirm that the Bluetooth of the testing device and the devices which it should discover is turned on and the other devices are discoverable? Try checking them via the Android OS Bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, they are all on and discoverable